# I'm missing functionality from $meteor.object

Tags: angular-meteor

I'am trying to migrate into new 1.3 api, unfortunately it looks like it's not only syntax that changed - whole functionality that made angular-meteor beauty, went gone. Before change i had object, lets say, post, i could do something like

```js
$scope.post.title = 'new title';
//and then save it with
$scope.post.save();
//or if i decided to discard settings,
$scope.post.reset();
```

This functionality was similar to way how PHP models works

From now on, we are left only with Mongo api, this means that in order to save changes, i have to manually $set every field im interested in - that is really ugly and unpractical.
I cant even think about reseting form..

```js
var cachePost = $scope.post;

$scope.post.title = 'new title'; 

$scope.reset(){
$scope.post = cachePost;
console.log($scope.post.title); // title
}
```

Is there any way to bring back the way it used to work?

Comment: without lurking into deprecated methods ;)

Comment: i should propably check if its possible to implement https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy